# How to call an API which is based on XML-RPC specification in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, xml-rpc, nuget-package

Here is my sample request,

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
 <methodCall>
  <methodName>login</methodName>
   <params>
    <param>
     <value>
      <struct>
       <member>
        <name>password</name>
        <value><string>XXXXXXXXXX</string></value>
       </member>
       <member>
        <name>username</name>
        <value><string>XXXX@XXX.com</string></value>
       </member>
    </struct>
  </value>
 </param>
 </params>
</methodCall>
```

Here is my sample successful response for the request:

```
<struct>
  <member>
    <name>id</name>
    <value><string>12345</string></value>
  </member>
  <member>
    <name>api_status</name>
    <value><int>200</int></value>
  </member>
</struct>
```

Question:

I was trying to call an **API** endpoint from a **.NET console application**. 
But, it didn't get connected to the server. Can anyone tell me how can I call this **API** endpoint using **C#**?

Comment: http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-2-5-0.html#2.1 - should help

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yes it was very helpful, Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 : Created a **Console Application** in **.NET**

Step 2 : Install the **NuGet** "**xml-rpc.net**"

Step 3: Created a sample **request** model class like this,

```
 public class request
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Step 4 : Created a sample **response** model class like this,

```
public class response
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }        
    }
```

Step 5 : Create an **interface** which is inherited form `IXmlRpcProxy` base class 
with the help of the **namespace** `using CookComputing.XmlRpc;`
and this interface must contain our endpoint  method and it should decorate with the **filter** `XmlRpcUrl` having the **API** resource.

```
    [XmlRpcUrl("https://api.XXX.com/XXX")]
    public interface FlRPC : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("login")]//endpoint name
        response login(request request);
    }
```

Step 6 : To make calls to an **XML-RPC server** it is necessary to use an instance of a **proxy** class.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            response response = new response();
            request request = new request();
            FlRPC proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<FlRPC>();
            request.password = "xxxxxxxx";
            request.username = "xxxx@xxxx.org";
            response = proxy.login(request);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The above **request**, **response** model class must contain all the properties and the property name should be slimier to the payload of the endpoint's request, response.

Comment: This is great, however what if I don't know the response I am getting back and just want to view the entire response instead?

Comment: I am getting this error: `response contains struct value with missing non-optional members: Result Status [response : struct mapped to type response]`