# Convert Odoo python implementations into ASP.NET

Tags: python, asp.net, web-services, odoo-14, odoo-15

I'm new to Odoo and referred documentation and implemented functions using python language. Now I want them to convert ASP.NET. Could you help me to do this task?

```
import xmlrpc.client     

url = 'http://localhost:8069'   
db = 'test_db'   
username = 'admin'  
password = 'admin'  

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))  
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.product', 'search', [[['type', '=', 'product']]])   
rec = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.product', 'read', [ids],
                                   {'fields': ['name', 'qty_available']})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647779/how-to-call-an-api-which-is-based-on-xml-rpc-specification-in-c

Comment: as the same api is exposed as jsonrpc you can try librarys for that to