# How to collect data from a different source in Odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

we have an e-commerce website which is developed in asp.net. We want to collect all the order invoice data in Odoo's accounts module and want to create a journal for every invoice.

Is anyone have any idea how to do that in an efficient and easy way?
There is xml-rpc but in odoo documentation, I noticed that xml-rpc aren't supporting in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

"XML-RPC is a remote procedure call (RPC) protocol which uses XML to encode its calls and HTTP as a transport mechanism."

This means you can actually call an XML RPC api with any languages able to deal with HTTP requests and responses.

You can see in this post how to call and RPC API with C# : [How to call an API which is based on XML-RPC specification in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647779/how-to-call-an-api-which-is-based-on-xml-rpc-specification-in-c)